# JQuery - iterating through multiple elements and replacing src and href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jinja2

I am making an image gallery website that stores thousands of images. To avoid lagging the client, I want to add pagination to only fetch X number of images at a time as the user clicks the next/previous button to go through the images.

An AJAX request containing the page number is sent to the backend when  the button is clicked, and the backend returns the new paginated image filenames in `data.images`

My goal is to loop through each image src and href attribute in the HTML and replace the values with the new image filename path so the new images show on the webpage.

HTML:

```html
<main class="row">
    {% for image in data["images"] %}
        <div class="image">
            <a href="static/images/{{ image.filename }}"  target="_blank">
                <img alt="image" src="static/images/{{ image.filename }}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</main>
```

JQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/get_images",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 
            page: 2,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // the backend successfully returns the new image filenames in data.images
            console.log(data.images);

            // not exactly sure what to add here
            // to iterate through all of the elements and replace each href and src with the new image filename
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: A `for` loop maybe?

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. assign some dynmamic attributes to the tags. do a for loop inside ajax success function with the dynamic attribute id's modify src and href.

```js
$('button').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/get_images",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 
            page: 2,
        },
        success: function(data) {
          for (i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
            var id = "static/images/"+data.images[i];
            $("[imageid='image"+i+"']").attr('src', id);
            $("[hrefid='image"+i+"']").attr('href', id); 
          }
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<main class="row">
    {% var i=0; %}
    {% for image in data["images"] %}
        <div class="image">
            <a href="static/images/{{ image.filename }}"  target="_blank" hrefid="image"+i>
                <img alt="image" src="static/images/{{ image.filename }}" imageid="image"+i>
            </a>
        </div>
     {% i++   %}
    {% endfor %}
</main>
```